# enabling in-line editing for a view in list definition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I'm currently creating some list definition for use in a SharePoint 2010 environment. In these definitions I need to to define a view which enables in-line editing. This is easily accomplished in the UI as well as from code by setting the InLine property of the SPView object to "TRUE", however I can't find any property of the CAML definition of the view to set the property.

I've looked at what Visual Studio supplies in the auto-complete for both attributes of the  element and immediate children of the same element and nothing seems to be relevant.

Anyone know if I'm looking in the entirely wrong place, or have any idea where to set this in the schema.xml of the list definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable Inline Editing in the View element of the List definition (Schema.xml) by defining the InlineEdit element and giving it a value of TRUE, like so:

```
<View ...>
  <ViewFields ... />
  <Query ... />
  <Aggregations Value="Off" />
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
  <Mobile ... />
  <InlineEdit>TRUE</InlineEdit>
  <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
  <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
  <ParameterBindings>
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
  </ParameterBindings>
</View>
```

Comment: I have no way of verifying that this is correct since I haven't actually done SharePoint work in the last year and a half or so, but resurrecting this is deserving of credit at any rate.

Comment: I posted the answer as I recently needed it and found this thread in my search.  Figured someone else might want to know how to do it, even if SP2010 is getting a bit dated.

Answer (score 1):

On a Quick Note,In SharePoint 2010 CAML Based view is obsolete. Though CAML based view will work in 2010 it will not be support for the next version of SharePoint. Considering that you are developing new List Definition IMHO I recommand to look in to the XSLT based views and see if you could get your requirement work in the XSLT.

1. [CAML Obsolete & View is based on XSLT](http://andreasglaser.net/post/2009/01/05/WSS-40-e28093-New-information-about-Windows-SharePoint-Services-40-SharePoint-2009.aspx)
2. [CAML Reference](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/12/31/sharepoint-2010-dev-tidbit-trouble-finding-the-caml-reference.aspx)

Comment: The obsolescence of CAML refers to the View Template, not the definition of of lists via templates nor the definition of other elements of views.